# Powershell - New-MgUserOnenotePage

Tags: powershell, microsoft-graph-api

I'm trying to use the Microsoft Graph SDK in PowerShell to automate the creation of a OneNote Page.
The problem is that the New-MgUserOnenotePage seems to require the page content to be Multipart and I don't know how to create that in PowerShell.

I keep getting the error: Page create requests require the content to be multipart, with a presentation part.

The Microsoft documentation is still very new, so no real examples for PowerShell. Can anyone help me with this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I am able to repo the issue , and this looks like a know bug - https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-powershell/issues/568 , you can add your comment on the same bug , so it will escalated in priority ,

For a workaround you can try through the graph explorer , please refer the doc - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/section-post-pages?view=graph-rest-1.0

POST [https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/onenote/sections/{id}/pages](https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/onenote/sections/%7Bid%7D/pages)
Content-type: multipart/form-data; boundary=MyPartBoundary198374

--MyPartBoundary198374
Content-Disposition:form-data; name="Presentation"
Content-Type:text/html

---- write your content in html format ------

Hope this help , thanks

Comment: If the answer is helpful, please click "Accept Answer" and kindly upvote it. If you have extra questions about this answer, please click "Comment" , thanks

Comment: Well I've also tried C# SDK, but seems there is also a bug in the SDK when creating a page (https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-dotnet/issues/1011). Is it possible to authenticate with: 



var interactiveCredential = new InteractiveBrowserCredential(options);
graphClient = new GraphServiceClient(interactiveCredential, scopes);

and then use the graphClient to do a normal HTTP Request or POST?

Comment: what error you got while trying in C# sdk?